# A service to search for RSS feeds?

Tags: web-services, search, rss

I am building an RSS Reader.  Some of the existing ones out there (for example, Pulse News for iPhone/iPad) have a search box where you can search for some term (example - "sports") and it will return a list of feeds that match your search criteria.  So in this example, you type in "sports", and it searches and then comes back with ESPN.com's news feed, Yahoo! Sports' news feed, etc. etc.

What search engine does that?  I've looked at Syndic8.com and it was kind of crap compared to whatever Pulse is using.  If you search for "sports" it returns feeds I've never even heard of from obscure sites.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look a the google feed api and espacially: https://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/ajaxfeeds/documentation/reference.html#findFeeds

Comment: Thank you so much, that was sufficient and I think its the same one Pulse uses.

Comment: For anyone else who stumbles upon this question, the correct address is:  "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/find?q=sports&v=1.0"

Comment: Looks like the Google Feed API is now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

2017 Answer here.

There's a service called Pine (which I run) that aggregate Blog RSS and JSON feeds, and it has a free API.

https://pinesearch.com